# Vagrant package version number/id

Tags: vagrant

I wish to add a version number to a box I'm packaging:

`vagrant package --output mynew.box`

The command will make the box show up as after I added it to Vagrant:

`mynew.box (virtualbox, 0)`

I want to specify the version number to be as:

`mynew.box (virtualbox, 1.6.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the flag `--box-version` when importing the box.

`vagrant init mybox/mybox --box-version 1.6.0`